# Very large Prestashop MySQL query cause large database usage

Tags: jquery, mysql, optimization, query-optimization, prestashop

Is there a way to optimize this query causing large database usage? The full query is full of ID records - so i croped to just

> IN (39,40,thousands of products ID's, 29674) GROUP BY

- **Number of overloaded records:** 108000528
- **Average number of overloaded records:** 216001
- **Number of repetitions:** 500
- **The longest / medium time of query execution:** 5.494 / 1.873
- **Average number of rows loaded / returned:** 216040/39
- **Number of questions that resulted in zero:** 86

**Analyzed SQL query:**

```
SELECT  p.*, product_shop.*, product_shop.id_category_default,
        pl.*, MAX(image_shop.`id_image`) id_image, il.legend,
        m.name manufacturer_name,
        MAX(pa.id_product_attribute) id_product_attribute,
        stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity
    FROM  `psy_category_product` cp
    LEFT JOIN  psy_category c  ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category)
    LEFT JOIN  `psy_product` p  ON p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
    INNER JOIN  psy_product_shop product_shop 
               ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product
              AND  product_shop.id_shop = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN  `psy_product_attribute` pa  ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
    LEFT JOIN  psy_product_attribute_shop product_attribute_shop
        ON (product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute
              AND  product_attribute_shop.id_shop = 1
              AND  product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN  psy_stock_available stock  ON (stock.id_product = p.id_product
              AND  stock.id_product_attribute =
                 IFNULL(`product_attribute_shop`.id_product_attribute, 0)
              AND  stock.id_shop = 1  )
    LEFT JOIN  psy_product_lang pl  ON (pl.id_product = p.id_product
              AND  pl.id_shop = 1
              AND  pl.id_lang = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN  `psy_image` i  ON (i.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)
    LEFT JOIN  psy_image_shop image_shop  ON (image_shop.id_image = i.id_image
              AND  image_shop.id_shop = 1
              AND  image_shop.cover=1 )
    LEFT JOIN  `psy_image_lang` il  ON (image_shop.`id_image` = il.`id_image`
              AND  il.`id_lang` = 1 )
    LEFT JOIN  psy_manufacturer m  ON (m.id_manufacturer = p.id_manufacturer)
    WHERE  product_shop.`active` = 1
      AND  product_shop.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")
      AND  c.id_category = 15
      AND  c.active = 1
      AND  p.id_product IN (39,40,thousands of products ID's, 29674)
    GROUP BY  product_shop.id_product
    ORDER BY  cp.position asc
    LIMIT  48,48;
```

Comment: create view of query

Comment: run your query with explain in front, it will show you how your query is treated and what the bottleneck is.

Comment: i want to help but im not mysql expert :/

Comment: He wants you to run the query `explain select p.*, product_shop.*, ...` (e.g. using phpmyadmin) and add the output of that to your question. It tells you/us how the query is executed (e.g. which indexes are used or rather missing, ...). Generally: even with correct indexes, a list of 1000 ids will require about 10 times as much time than using 100, so maybe check if you have a different criteria to describe the list. It might be possible to rewrite the query to utilize the `limit`, or more efficient pagination. Is this a default prestashop query or a customized query?

Comment: Thanks guys for hint. @Solarflare this is pure pagination prestashop query...

Comment: What does "overloaded" mean?  What are you repeating?  Are the times in seconds or ms?  What is a zero question?

Comment: @HardeepSingh - `VIEWs` are syntactic sugar; they doe not provide any performance.

Comment: We'll help explain the `EXPLAIN`.  But you need to provide it.

Comment: view are pre complied sql query. also reduce the complexity of query

Answer (score 0):

`` smells like a many-to-many mapping table.  Follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .

Then, let's start by focusing on the critical part of the query:

```
SELECT  p.`id_product`,
        ps.id_category_default
    FROM  `psy_category_product` cp
    LEFT JOIN  psy_category c   ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category)
    LEFT JOIN  `psy_product` p  ON  p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`
    INNER JOIN  psy_product_shop AS ps
               ON  ps.id_product = p.id_product
              AND  ps.id_shop = 1 
    WHERE  ps.`active` = 1
      AND  ps.`visibility` IN ("both", "catalog")
      AND  c.id_category = 15
      AND  c.active = 1
      AND  p.id_product IN (39,40,29674)
    GROUP BY  ps.id_product
    ORDER BY  cp.position asc
    LIMIT  10;
```

(Adjust the id_product list so that something comes out.)

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for those 3 tables, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

The rest of the table seem to be simply lookups.

It is unclear whether the `GROUP BY` is needed.  If it is not, then get rid of it.